# nswag generated service has no return logic

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, nswag

I have a asp.net WebAPI service for user login that takes an email and password.  The api method has the following signature.  LoginDto has two fileds, Email and password.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDto dto)
```

Once the user is authenticated, WebAPI returns an object that has token and Id:

```
    return Ok(new { Token = GenerateJwtTokenFromClaims(claims), Id=user.Id });
```

On the client side (Blazor app), I used `nswag` command line tool by running `nswag run` and it "successfully" generated the `Service` and `Contract` files.  Everything complies.  `nswag` generated code is pasted below.

When I want to use the login nswag `Service`, I have the following method (I also have an overloaded method with `CancellationToken` but I only use this method):

```
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task Login2Async(LoginDto body)
    {
        return Login2Async(body, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

The question that I have is that how do I get the response out of the nswag-generated-code that the WebAPI login sent back to the client?  When I try to assign a var to the method, I get `Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable` which makes sense since I don't see a return type.  I also don't see any logic in the `nswag` generated `service` file to return the response to the caller.  How do I get the response back from the nswag generated API call?  Is there an option I have to set in `nswag run` to get a response object back?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
  public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Login2Async(LoginDto body, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/api/Account/Login");
    
            var client_ = _httpClient;
            var disposeClient_ = false;
            try
            {
                using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
                {
                    var content_ = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, _settings.Value));
                    content_.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                    request_.Content = content_;
                    request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("POST");
    
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
                    var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                    request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);
    
                    var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var disposeResponse_ = true;
                    try
                    {
                        var headers_ = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                        if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                                headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                        }
    
                        ProcessResponse(client_, response_);
    
                        var status_ = (int)response_.StatusCode;
                        if (status_ == 200)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        if (status_ == 400)
                        {
                            var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<ProblemDetails>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            throw new ApiException<ProblemDetails>("Bad Request", status_, objectResponse_.Text, headers_, objectResponse_.Object, null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
                            throw new ApiException("The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (" + status_ + ").", status_, responseData_, headers_, null);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (disposeResponse_)
                            response_.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (disposeClient_)
                    client_.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to the NSwag team, the issue is resolved.  I was returning anonymous object from the WebAPI method.  The correct way to do is the following.  Notice that `IActionResult` was changed to `ActionResult` passing a concrete object to return to the caller.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<LoginDtoResponse>> Login(LoginDto dto)
```

then returning

```
 return Ok(new LoginDtoResponse { Token = GenerateJwtTokenFromClaims(claims), Id=user.Id });
```

After that I did that, the following code was generated:

```
                    if (status_ == 200)
                    {
                        var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<LoginDtoResponse>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        return objectResponse_.Object;
                    }
```